# Ansible: Register iterating with the loop

Tags: ansible

I am using register with a loop in my Ansible playbook, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a results attribute.

```yaml
tasks:
- name: checking the module
  command: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - date
    - uptime
  register: output

- debug:
    msg: "{{ output.results }}"
```

I am getting the `outputs.results` data but I need to filter that data with the `stdout_lines`. I tried `output.results.stdout` and `output.results.item.stdout`, but both did not work.

Any idea as how can we get the output only for the `stdout` of these commands not the entire results?

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the output results or access the position [0]:
`"{{output.results[0]}}"`

You are storing 2 stdout so you need to iterate the results var:

```yaml
tasks:
  -   name: checking the module
      command: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - date
        - uptime
      register: output
  -   debug:
        msg: "{{item.stdout}}"
      loop: "{{output.results}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the registered output through `map` to pick the value of `stdout_lines` for each item's dictionary:

```
tasks:
- name: checking the module
  command: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - date
    - uptime
  register: output

- debug:
    msg: "{{ output.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines')}}"
```